# Replace Imports Statement and Load DLL in code to use object?

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-assembly, nlog

I currently have applications that use a free NLog logging library (a DLL) which I reference in my VB.NET project (Imports statement, declare it, etc.).

I have written a Class Library (DLL) that contains some common functionality to my applications which also utilizes the free NLog logging library.  My issue is that when I upgrade the NLog.dll for my main application, I also need to go and update my Class Library application.  I don't want to have to update/re-compile class library each time and would like to pass in the current object or load the NLog assembly dynamically (in-code).

In my class library project, I have something like this:

```
Imports NLog

Private mLog As Logger

Public ReadOnly Property Log As Logger
    Get
        If (mLog Is Nothing) Then
            mLog = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger
        End If
        Return mLog
    End Get
End Property

Later on used as:
Log.Error("Message...")
```

I was hoping to pass in the NLog object into a function and then somehow load the NLog assembly and declare a variable to use it.

```
''Imports NLog

Private mLog As Object

Public ReadOnly Property Log As Object
        Get
            If (mLog Is Nothing) Then
                Dim theAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "NLog.dll")
                Dim typeLogManager As Type = theAssembly.GetType("NLog.LogManager")
 Dim myObj As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(typeLogManager)
                mLog = typeLogManager.InvokeMember("GetCurrentClassLogger", BindingFlags.Default Or BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, myObj, Nothing)
            End If
        Return mLog
    End Get
End Property
```

I thought this would create the "CurrentClassLogger" object, but it keeps failing with the error "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." on the line

```
Dim myObj As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(typeLogManager)
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here or what I'm missing.  I would like to be able to create the Logger similar to as if I had referenced (imported) in the NLog assembly.  Any help and sample code is greatly appreciated!

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the `LogManager` type like you already did. Then get the static `GetCurrentClassLogger` method and invoke it:

```
Dim typeLogManager As Type = theAssembly.GetType("NLog.LogManager")
Dim currentLoggerMethod As MethodInfo = typeLogManager.GetMethod("GetCurrentClassLogger", Type.EmptyTypes)
mLog = currentLoggerMethod.Invoke(Nothing, Nothing)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Any possible way to retain the intellisense of the Logger (the object that is returned to mLog) without casting it as Logger (which would require me to include the imports statement)?  I'd still like to be able to have the intellisense and I know I can't get that right now since mLog is declared as Object.  BTW - I had just got this working, but much clumsier:   Dim myObj As Object=Activator.CreateInstance(typeLogManager, BindingFlags.CreateInstance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)

Comment: No that is not possible.

Comment: Which versions of NLog you like to combine?